# FFMPEG overlaying video with image removes audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to generate a video from a given video and an image, I'm also pading and scaling the video.
This command works great and it generates the expected result, However in the resulted video there is no sound!

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -i rj2k15y3.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=440:440,setsar=1:1,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:120:color=white[padded]; [padded]overlay=0:0[out]" -map "[out]" -y -metadata title="video1" result.mp4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a map statement is made, only expressly mapped streams are muxed into the output.

Change to `...[padded]overlay=0:0" -y ...` Or add `-map 0:a`