# Python ffmpeg: overlaying videos is dropping all audio

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am using ffmpeg-python ([source](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)) to create the effect where you add a blurred background to fill in the sides of a tall vertical video as shown below: [image: blurred video background]

The problem is that the output has no audio attached. Since the clips are the same, I want to keep the audio from one of the clips in the final output. How can I keep the audio? (I don't want to overlay the audio from both and get an echo effect, however!)

This is the function I'm using:

```
import ffmpeg
def add_blurred_bg():
    HEIGHT = 720 
    WIDTH = 1280
    in_file = ffmpeg.input('input.mp4')
    probe = ffmpeg.probe('input.mp4')
    video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
    iw=int(video_stream['width'])
    ih=int(video_stream['height'])
    nw = HEIGHT*iw/ih
    (
        ffmpeg
        .overlay(
            in_file.filter('scale', WIDTH, -2).crop(0,(WIDTH*HEIGHT/nw-HEIGHT)/2,WIDTH,HEIGHT).filter('gblur', sigma=40),
            in_file.filter('scale', -2, HEIGHT),
            x=(WIDTH-nw)/2
        )
        .output('output.mp4')
        .run()
    )
```

Comment: The code for blurring is pretty smart...

Comment: Thanks @Xilpex. Originally I was blowing up the video, blurring it, then cropping it. This took a long time since I would be blurring a huge video. The procedure I'm using here is from modifying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618683/5196039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to do it *keep* the audio style? Can you mix the audio and video? If so, this is a messy, but functioning example:

```
import ffmpeg
import os

def add_blurred_bg():
    HEIGHT = 720 
    WIDTH = 1280
    inp = 'input.mp4'
    os.system("ffmpeg -i " + inp + " -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3")
    print("extracting audio...")
    in_file = ffmpeg.input(inp)
    probe = ffmpeg.probe('input.mp4')
    video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
    iw=int(video_stream['width'])
    ih=int(video_stream['height'])
    nw = HEIGHT*iw/ih
    (
       ffmpeg
       .overlay(
            in_file.filter('scale', WIDTH, -2).crop(0,(WIDTH*HEIGHT/nw-HEIGHT)/2,WIDTH,HEIGHT).filter('gblur', sigma=40),
            in_file.filter('scale', -2, HEIGHT),
            x=(WIDTH-nw)/2
        )
        .output('outputPartial.mp4')
        .run()
    )
    print("bluring...")
    os.system("ffmpeg -i outputPartial.mp4 -i music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.mp4")
    print("mixing...")
    os.remove("outputPartial.mp4")
    os.remove("music.mp3")
    print("cleaning up...")
    print("done!")
```

I don't know why you have that problem, but here is a workaround.

**STEP 1:** Extract the music

**STEP 2:** Blur the video

**STEP 3:** Mix the audio and the video

**STEP 4:** Clean-Up

Comment: This worked for me. Unfortunately, ffmpeg does not have all the audio features implemented yet https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/26 so I had to use your `os.system` codes. Two things to note: 1) in your first os.system call, you need to have a space before `-f`. 2) I had to change your final os.system call to `os.system("ffmpeg -i outputPartial.mp4 -i music.mp3 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.mp4")` Since the line you gave me was giving this error "Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
Conversion failed!"

Answer (score 1):

The other answer will work, but there's a less complex approach that will fix the audio.

Change this line:

```
.output('output.mp4')
```

to this:

```
.output(in_file.audio, 'output.mp4')
```

### Explanation

When ffmpeg is given a `-map` option, it drops all audio/video streams which are not explicitly part of the map statement. Internally, ffmpeg-python uses map to implement overlays, and does not explicitly map the audio. See also [FFMPEG overlaying video with image removes audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783941/ffmpeg-overlaying-video-with-image-removes-audio).

So, the fix is to explicitly map the input audio to the output.

Full working code:

```
import ffmpeg
def add_blurred_bg():
    HEIGHT = 720 
    WIDTH = 1280
    in_file = ffmpeg.input('input.mp4')
    probe = ffmpeg.probe('input.mp4')
    video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
    iw=int(video_stream['width'])
    ih=int(video_stream['height'])
    nw = HEIGHT*iw/ih
    (
        ffmpeg
        .overlay(
            in_file.filter('scale', WIDTH, -2).crop(0,(WIDTH*HEIGHT/nw-HEIGHT)/2,WIDTH,HEIGHT).filter('gblur', sigma=40),
            in_file.filter('scale', -2, HEIGHT),
            x=(WIDTH-nw)/2
        )
        .output(in_file.audio, 'output.mp4')
        .run()
    )
```