# FFMPEG overlay video over image using movie filter resulting video with no sound

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to overlay srinked video on the top of single image.
I use movie filter to do that. like this

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i Coronavirus00000000.jpg -vf "movie=C\\:/\Users/\Toshiba/\Pictures/\test vcp/\shopi pro.mp4,scale=1180:-1[inner];[in][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]" -y out.mp4
```

It's work. but the problem, the audio from video is removed. The final video out.mp4 has no sound, even though the original video has.

I have read answer on this threat [FFMPEG overlaying video with image removes audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783941/ffmpeg-overlaying-video-with-image-removes-audio)

That recommend to Change into `...[padded]overlay=0:0" -y ...` Or `add -map 0:a`

But I don't understand how to implement that answer into movie filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice inputs/sources you have:

1. an input image ("Coronavirus00000000.jpg")
2. a [movie source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#movie-1) which by default selects a video stream

so you don't have any audio input stream selected/opened. To do so I'd recommend open every file as a standard ffmpeg input (`-i <file>`) and then configure a complex filtering graph that utilizes them.

In your example that would be:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Coronavirus00000000.jpg -i C\\:/\Users/\Toshiba/\Pictures/\test vcp/\shopi pro.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1180:-1[inner];[0:v][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]" -map '[out]' -map 1:a -y out.mp4
```

where:

- `-i Coronavirus00000000.jpg` opens your image file as input #0
- `-i C\\:/\Users/\Toshiba/\Pictures/\test vcp/\shopi pro.mp4` opens your video file with video and audio streams as input #1
- `[1:v]scale=1180:-1[inner]` scales the input's #1 video stream
- `[0:v][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]` overlays the scaled video onto input's #0 video stream
- `-map '[out]'` selects overlayed video stream (tagged as `[out]`) for output video stream
- `-map 1:a` selects input's #1 audio stream for output audio stream

Comment: it gives me an error like this

`[image2 @ 068446c0] Invalid stream specifier: '[out]'.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream map ''[out]'' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.`

Comment: it works, after i change the single quote of `-map '[out]'` to `-map "[out]"`. thank you very much.
but could you explain in more details about this line `[0:v][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]` why its use `[0:v]` while #0 is an image, not `[1:v]`?

Comment: @HerahadiAn I assumed you want to overlay a video onto an image, so acording to [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1):
`It takes two inputs and has one output. The first input is the "main" video on which the second input is overlaid.`